# Tornado Install Issue

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to install tornado (pip install tornado) and am getting the following error...

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_username/tornado/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TLunUn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_username/tornado
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 62: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I haven't been able to find anything to explain this in the context of a Tornado issue... if anyone has any ideas that would be great

Comment: The error doesn't look tornado-specific.  Can you install other things with pip?  Are there non-ascii characters in your path or home directory name?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while installing another program. It was not a decoding problem but a permission problem. Try the following:

```
    pip install --user tornado
```

I hope that works for you as well.