# pip install tornado fails in VS2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, tornado

Trying to install Tornado on my Win10 VS2017 for Python 3.6 64-bit using this command `pip install tornado` and am getting this error:

`----- Installing 'pip install tornado' -----
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (18.0)
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install
----- Failed to install 'pip install tornado' -----`

I tried to also to download the Git zip and use this command `pip install -Iv https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/78/6e7b5af12c12bdf38ca9bfe863fcaf53dc10430a312d0324e76c1e5ca426/tornado-5.1.1.tar.gz`
(as referenced here: [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip))

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ shows

> Tornado 5.x runs on Python 2.7, and 3.4+

I tried this as well `pip install --user tornado` as referenced here: [Tornado Install Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066334/tornado-install-issue)

All options wind up with the same eventual error: failed to install.

I'm guessing it's related to this: `(from versions: )` in the error, but I am rather new to pip/python

---

Tried `pip install -vvv …` as requested by hoefling (there's more above this in the output)

`No matching distribution found for install
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 308, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 543, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for install
----- Failed to install 'pip install -vvv https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/0e/8ec7ed219cb35fffe2f2cddbfa02b47ba5d23dd9026a41b3f2bdd63cdec3/tornado-5.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' -----`

Comment: It looks like you have Python 3.6 - can you confirm that by running `pip -V`/`python -V`? If my guess is correct - what output do you get when running `pip install -vvv https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/0e/8ec7ed219cb35fffe2f2cddbfa02b47ba5d23dd9026a41b3f2bdd63cdec3/tornado-5.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`?

Comment: @hoefling - ran the install and got a lengthy error - I edited the original to add the results (wouldn't fit here)

Comment: Hmm, then it's either not Python 3.6 you're having, or it's not a 64bit version. What do you get when you enter `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe" --version` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe" -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize)"`?

Comment: @hoefling 3.6.6 and 9223372036854775807, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I re-RTM, and noticed

> In addition to the requirements which will be installed automatically by pip or setup.py install, the following optional packages may be useful....

So I downloaded the stable zip, extracted and ran:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe" setup.py install` and it worked like a charm.

I'm not well versed enough in the ways of pip or python to know why this worked and the other approaches did not.